# Nuxt.js: How to override scrollBehaviour for a single route change

Tags: javascript, scroll, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt-page where I scroll to the top on every router change. We defined this in the nuxt.config.js

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  return ({ x: 0, y: 0 })
}
```

Now I have one single Navigation link which is a little special: «Contact» does not lead to a new page with just the contact information, but instead it should go to the footer where the contact details are written on every page.
So I added a link (not a nuxtlink) to link to the `#contact` anchor in the footer.

```
  <a class="Submenu__link Submenu__link--contact" href="#contact">
    Contact
  </a>
```

This does not work though because it registers a route change and sets the page to the top again. (At least that is my assumption).
I tried to execute some function to set the scrollTop property but then I see a flicker, where it scrolls a bit but is then reset to the top:

```
  <li class="Submenu__item">
    <a @click="closeNavAndScroll" class="Submenu__link Submenu__link--contact" href="#contact">
      Contact
    </a>
  </li>
```

And I declared a method (closing nav works):

```
closeNavAndScroll () {
  this.closeNavMenu()
  window.scrollTop(400)
}
```

So I thought I find some information here:
https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#scrollBehavior

But as far as I could understand there is only a declaration for setting the scrollBehaviour for all routes.
Can I somehow say whenever the route includes `#contact` I don't want the app to mess with my scroll position?

Thanks for any help on this.

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create your `#contact` anchor as you did, but change the scroll behavior to handle it:

```
scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (to.hash) {
    return {selector: to.hash}
  } else {
    return {x: 0, y: 0}
  }
}
```

Comment: See also https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/5okcgo/vuerouter_route_transitions_and_improper_scroll/ where they add `if (savedPosition) {
        return savedPosition
      }`

Comment: Hello, in case you have time to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55196920/nuxt-js-and-anchors), than you