# Nuxt.js and anchors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

How to deal with anchors (within the same page) in Nuxt.js ?

Problem is  the URL stays always on the base `localhost:3000/`
I want to have anchors displayed on the URL too: `localhost:3000/#anchor1`, `localhost:3000/#anchor2`, `localhost:3000/#anchor3` … etc.

It seems `<nuxt-link :to=(/#anchorid)> Inner link </nuxt-link>` does not do the job.

How to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If using `locales`

```
<nuxt-link 
  :to="localePath({ name: 'index', hash: '#anchor1'})" 
  v-text="Anchor 1" 
  alt="Anchor 1">
</nuxt-link>
```

Else

```
<nuxt-link to="/anchor1" v-text="Anchor 1" />
```